# Is there anyway to make a macro to redeploy an application in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

Every time I need to redeploy something (for example in Glassfish), I have to right click glassfish, click add or remove, select the source and then deploy it. Now, Iam not asking to deploy with one button the same source everytime. I would like just to open that window to select the source and then deploy it. This will save me and a lot of other people from 2 unnecessary clicks.

Comment: I don't know if that functionality exists in Eclipse without extensions, but with the GlassFish Tools plugin, one can press CTRL+ALT+P for republishing _all_ deployed modules.

Comment: Thank you I will try it and tell you what happened !

Answer (score 0):

I found that selecting the project and with Control+Shift+X and then R you can redeploy. But this will also launch a browser within eclipse which I don't need.